# Where is the tesseract executable file located on MacOS, and how to define it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have made a code using pytesseract and whenever I run it, I get this error:

`TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path`

I have installed tesseract using HomeBrew and also `pip` installed it.

Comment: Your question is unclear as to what you are doing. Please show a **Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example** of your code.

Comment: Use `which tesseract` [command](https://ss64.com/osx/which.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If installed with Homebrew, it will be located in */usr/local/bin/tesseract* by default. To verify this, run `which tesseract` in the terminal as Dmitrrii Z. mentioned.

If it's there, you can set it up in your python environment by adding the following line to your python script, after importing the library:
`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/tesseract'`

Comment: I have tesseract installed at that file path but still when I try to import I get the Module Not Found error.

Answer (score 0):

This is another location where you can find it if none of the above solutions work.

`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/opt/homebrew/bin/tesseract'`

but after `brew install tesseract` you should `which tesseract` to get the exact location